# Difference between variable selection technique and WOE screening

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, logit, stepwise-regression

I am using the WOE technique  in logistic regression. Using Information Value (IV) of the variables,  I am considering the variables with IV > 0.1 and discarding ones with < 0.1

I feel even the multiple-variable selection techniques like stepwise regression also does the same.

I found an R package 'Information' documentation here https://github.com/klarsen1/Information
which tells otherwise.

> Note that the purpose of this step should not to be confused with that
>   of multiple-variable selection techniques, such as stepwise
>   regression, where the variables that go into the final model are
>   selected. Rather, this is a precursory step designed to ensure that
>   the approaches deployed during the final modeling phases are set up
>   for success.

I am confused after reading this. Can anyone please state the difference in different words.

Comment: Please say just something about what is WOE screeming technique.

Comment: @ttnphns, please check this out.
http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/information-value-and-weight-of-evidencebanking-case/